# Magento 2 - How to show custom added attributes on product view page below "add to cart" Button?

Tags: php, magento2

I have added Closure attribute in magento2 luma theme and able to see in grid but when click on product the attribute not shows like default attributes color, size, etc.

Comment: Code snippet to show what you're doing will help those who can help you provide more actionable information.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your attribute in your product template file to get the attribute value

```
$product->getClosure();
```